# Wizards Page Changing Based on Screen resolution

Tags: swt, jface

I have a dialog with a wizard containing multiple wizard page. The wizard page appears differently for different screen resolution. 
Some contents of wizardpage is missing if the  screen resolution changed to small to Medium.
Even when the screen Resolution Changes the Wizard page should not loose the content.
 Please let me know is there any way so that wizard page gets adjusted with screen resolution changes.

Main Page

```java
@Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        setControl(container);

        createDialogArea(container);
        DataBindingContext context = initDataBindings();
        setControl(container);
        setPageComplete(false);
        }
```

First Page extends Mainpage :

```java
@Override
        public void createControl(Composite parent) {

            super.createControl(parent); }
```

Have wizard and wizard Dialog

```java
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
                // create the top level composite for the dialog area

                Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    }
    @Override
            protected Point getInitialSize() {
                return new Point(550, 580);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Show us an [mcve]

Comment: Edit your question and put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `getInitialSize` and specifying a specific size (550 x 580) for the dialog. This will override the size that the Shell calculates for the dialog. Don't do this unless you have a very good reason for setting the wizard dialog size.

Comment: Based on Resolution how to change the Dialog.I should set the getInitialSize   a specific size (550 x 580) for the dialog. So Based on Resolution the font size should reduced.

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do that.

Comment: how to set the Dialog page when the  the System font preferences changes from small to medium  or small to large or medium to large...Is there any straight forward way to do...At any preferences it should behave same..........??

Comment: I don't know of a way to handle that.